# Worpdress - How to declare jQuery as the first thing at the head tag

Tags: wordpress, minify

I am using a JS minifier and merger excluding jquery. But the minified file is coming before the jQuery and i get "jQuery" is not found in console. How can i put jQuery as the first item in the head tag?

Comment: Do you have any code to show how you are enqueuing your javascript file?

Comment: @bswatson With WP-Rocket plugin.

Comment: You are working with in theme?

Comment: can you please show us your code and a screenshot of your source code